# How to get password from HTML form to my views in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am getting username form HTML form  but I'm not able to get password from input password field to my views in dajngo.

views.py

```
def logMeIn(request):
    username = request.POST.get("inputEmail", False)
    password = request.POST.get("inputPassword", False)
    return HttpResponse(password)
```

my login.html file is ....

```
<form method='POST' action = 'logMeIn/'>
<div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
</div>

<div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
</div>
</form>
```

please help me on this ,Thanks & Regards.,

**Update**

```
<div class="form-label-group">
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
  <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this to

```
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Password" required>
```

When you submit a form, each of the form fields is identified by `name` attribute in the input field.
You miss `name` attribute for the password field. So, it's value not get in view.

**Update**

```
def logMeIn(request):
    username = request.POST.get("inputEmail", False)
    password = request.POST.get("inputPassword", False)
    print(password)
    return HttpResponse(password)
```

see the output in terminal.

Comment: Please give an explanation to your answer.

Comment: can add your `login.html` with my change?

Comment: sorry. I see same thing, you previously added

Answer (score 1):

To get anything in the request you need to provide a `name` to the field.

Just like you have provided `name="inputEmail"` to the email field.

```
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
```

You need to provide a name to password field as well -

```
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass some data from a HTML form to the server side language using a form, each input of the form which needs to be passed should include a 'name' attribute. From your provided HTML code it can be clearly seen that you've name attribute for the email field but not for the password field.
In order to fix this simply change the password input field to following:

```
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
```